# Pass fetch returned promise as Context value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the fetch request response from a helper function to a ReactJS Context.

This is my Context:

```
const SomeContext = React.createContext();

const SomeProvider = SomeContext.Provider;
const SomeConsumer = SomeContext.Consumer;

export {SomeProvider, SomeConsumer};
```

This is my helper function:

```
function FetchU() {
  const zx = localStorage.getItem("zx");
  const xx = localStorage.getItem("xx");
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      accesstoken: accessToken,
      userid: userid
    }
  };
  if (userid !== null) {
    fetch(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/authenticated/get-roles",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });

  } else {
    console.log("not loggedin === no user permissions.");
  }
}
export default FetchU;
```

This is how I utilize my `Context Provider`

```
 <PermissionsProvider value="something">
     <Child Component />
     <SecondChild Component />
     <ThirdChild Component />
 </PermissionsProvider>
```

My helper function is triggered by an event manually inside the application, so there is the option that the `value=something` might actually be equal to `null` or `undefined`.

I wanna place the values from the `FetchU` function in place of the `value=something`. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What I'll do for your case is define your context with object as default values

```
// Context default values.
const Context = React.createContext({
  value: '',
  loading: false,
  updateContext: () => {},
});
```

Then create a Provider on top of the `Context.Provider`

```
const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const handleUpdateContext = useCallback(async () => {
    // Call your api here
    setLoading(true);
    let newValue;
    try {
      newValue = await mockAPICall();
    } catch (err) {
      // handle err
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
    // Then update context value with your result.
    setValue(newValue);
  }, []);
  const context = {
    value,
    loading,
    updateContext: handleUpdateContext,
  };
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={context}>
      {/* I usually do this for extra flexibility */}
      {typeof children === 'function' ? children(context) : children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then use it in your app like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <div>
        <Context.Consumer>
          {({ value, loading }) => {
            if (loading) return 'Loading...';
            return (
              <label>
                Result in context :
                <pre>
                  {JSON.stringify(value, '\t', '')}
                </pre>
              </label>
            );
          }}
        </Context.Consumer>
        <Context.Consumer>
          {({ updateContext }) => (
            <button onClick={updateContext}>Simulate API Call</button>
          )}
        </Context.Consumer>
      </div>
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

There are some things to consider, maybe you can make use of `useReducer` if the operation becomes more complex. You can also add `error` state in case there's any API error.

Here is the working code sandbox that I've prepared for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-demo-to1rn?from-embed

Hope it helps !